# Deserialization spring page object

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I'm working on two Spring Boot API that both have controllers returning Spring Page objects.
The serialization is working fine with Jackson, but I can't find any solution to deserialize it using Jackson.

I have the following error :

```
cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

Since Page is an interface, and PageImpl does not seem to have the proper constructors, I understand why Jackson can't do the job.

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: you should extract the Collection<?> from the Pageable object and return it. can you post your controller code?

Comment: My controller return a Page<MyObject>, which works fine when requesting with postman. There is no collection inside a Pageable object. It is when trying to deserializing it thaht Jakcon throw an error

Comment: do all the members of your object have getters? do you have a 0-args constructor? are you using lombok? sometimes Jackson can't read or write an object when some of the fields don't have access methods. please post the class of the object you are trying to serialize in your response, and the exception you are getting from Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should look like this way

```
    public Page<YourClass> post(@PageableDefault Pageable pageable) {
        return service.post(pageable);
}
```

When you are returning result you should use `Page`. When you are getting you should use `Pageable`. Note `@PageableDefault` is not mandatory. it is just setting default values if not specified.

Comment: My controller does look like that. But when I'm fetching data from this endpoint inside a java client, Jackson can't deserialize it into a Page object

Comment: Could you provide your controller and serializable object code?